# Activity Approve From super admin in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, user-roles

I am using Magento 2.2.6, and I need to create two admin user, in which one user change anything, it should be mandatory for another user will approve that. then only the changes will affect. 
I saw advance permission modules, but this feature is not there. 
if any module is available, please let me know or tell me how I can achieve this in Magento 2.

Comment: Hy @Sam,you want to create two admin user,one is super admin who have all permission to access,another one who have only limited permission to access file right

Comment: @Ajithkumar, something like that, but second admin has edit permission of product. but that edit action should be approved by super admin

Comment: Is my answer is helpfull for you?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 :** Login to super admin

**Step 2 :** Navigate System -> User Role -> Add New Role

**-----ROLE INFO ------**

**1. Role name :** Enter Role name like Sales Person,etc..

**2. Your Password :** enter super admin password here

[image]

**------- ROLE RESOURCE ---------**

Check option in role resource based on checked super admin give access to new user.

*User admin can manage permission role at any time*

**Step 4 :** Navigate to System -> All user -> Add New User

**Role info =>** fill all new user information and login details

[image]

**Roll Resource =>**  Assign new user role what you are create in user role section.

[image]

Finally new account is created...

Now user user can login using their credential and new user have permission to access only catalog section

**------- New user admin panel ---------**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ajithkumar , like that we should give the access of catalog. now subadmin will edit some catalog. after that how we can make it pending for for the superadmin approval on the changes.

Comment: No need to wait for superadmin approvael once sub-admin modified somethings in catalog section ( like sub-admin update any product inventory ) it will automatically updated without any admin approval

Comment: You wanna wait still super admin approval when sub-domain will did any changes in it\

Comment: yes, i want  to still super admin need to approve. it should not be automatically

Comment: You need to customise @sam